# How to repeat some action certain times on Vim?

Tags: macros, vim, repeat

In Vim, I usually want to repeat some series of commands some times. Say, I want to comment 5 lines, I would use

```
I//<Esc>j
.j.j.j.j
```

Is there any way to repeat the last ".j" part several times?

Comment: You mean something like `5`,`j`?

Comment: This is a round-about answer to your needs, if not the direct question.  What you seem to be doing here is commenting 5 lines of code.  If this is your only requirement, then you should use the NERD Commenter add-on.  This add on allows you to type `5\cc`, which comments the current line and the 4 following lines of code. `5\cs` would do the same, but insted of adding `//` line comments it will add `/*` and `*/` to block-comment your lines. Much more versatile.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

One way to do this is to assign your key sequence to a macro, then run the macro once followed by the `@@` run-last-macro command. For example:

```
qa.jq@a@@
```

If you know how many times you want to repeat the macro, you can use `4@@` or whatever.

Comment: 8 year old answer and this still works.  A testament to the power of vim.

Answer (score 16):

You can visually select the lines you want to repeat it on, type `:normal! .` to make vim use `.` on each line. Because you started with a visual selection, it ends up looking like this:

```
:'<,'>normal! .
```

However, if you're adding and removing `//` comments alot, you might find the following mappings useful:

```
" add // comment with K
noremap K :s,^\(//\)\=,//,e <BAR> nohls<CR>j
" remove // comment with CTRL+K
noremap <C-K> :s,^//,,e <BAR> nohls<CR>j
```

You can use `5K` to comment 5 lines, you can use visual mode to select your lines first, or you can just hammer `K` until you've commented everything you want.

Answer (score 12):

Regarding your specific example, I prefer to do multiple-line insertion using visual block mode (accessed with `Ctrl-v`). For example, if I had the following lines:

```
This should be a comment.
So should this.
This is definitely a comment.
Is this a comment? Yes.
```

I'd go to the top first character in the top line, hit `Ctrl-v` to enter visual block mode, navigate to last line (maybe using `3j` to move down 3 lines, maybe using `4g` to go directly to 4th line, or maybe simply `G` to go the end), then type `I// <esc>` to insert the comments on all the lines at once:

```
// This should be a comment.
// So should this.
// This is definitely a comment.
// Is this a comment? Yes.
```

Also, there's a very handy commenter/un-commenter plugin that supports many languages [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1528). It's easier than manually inserting/removing comments.

Comment: I use this one: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173

Pretty nice.

Comment: Hmm, this `Ctrl-V` method doesn't work for me... Only inserts on the first line.  Maybe it's because I'm still on vim 7.2...

Comment: No, plain vim... Actually I think it wasn't working for me earlier because I was exiting with Ctrl-C instead of Esc and not realizing it was different.  It works now. (Although I still don't know why it works with I/A/s but not i/a...)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. Do something
2. Exit to normal mode
3. Type, for example, `22.`

The last commands will repeats 22 times.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular example. you could also use a range `.,.5s#^#//#` (to do this and the next 5 lines) or a visual block (hit v, then select the text you want) followed by `:%s#^#//#`.

Comment: You could also use ":s#^#//# 5" (the line count is at the end).

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to set marks and run substitutions over that range:

```
ma
jjjj
mb
:'a,'bs,^,// ,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat a macro by appending a count before the macro. For example, if you recorded a macro to the `a` register and you wanted to perform it five times, you would type this:

```
5@a
```